# Can't select child div jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

```
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      some text
    </div>
    <div class='class4'>
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select `div.class1` without `div.class4`, but this doesn't work.

```
$('.class1').not('.class4')
```

Comment: The `.class4` div is a child of `.class1` so cannot be avoided. This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: what do you want expected result ?? plz briefly into your questions

Comment: I want to select all content from div.class1 but without content of div.class4

Comment: @Oloji: what are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select all content from `div.class1` but without [...] `div.class4`

You can use the attribute selector for this:

- `div[class]` means any `div` which has a `class` attribute.
- `div[class="class4"]` means any `div` which has a `class` attribute with the value `class4`.
- `div[class!="class4"]` means any `div` which has a `class` attribute with a value *which isn't* `class4`.

So your selector needs to be:

```
div div[class!="class4"]
```

ie. any `div` inside another `div` where the classname is not `class4`.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready (

    function() {
        $('div div[class!="class4"]').css('borderWidth','3px');
    }
);
```

```css
div {
margin: 12px;
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class1">

<div class="class2">
<div class="class3">
some text
</div>
<div class="class4">
some text
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

---

For the sake of completeness, here are the jQuery vs. javascript equivalents...

**jQuery:**

```
    function() {
        $('div div[class!="class4"]').css('borderWidth','3px');
    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
var selectedDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div div:not(.class4)');

for (var i = 0; i < selectedDivs.length; i++) {
    selectedDivs[i].style.borderWidth = '3px';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`not('.class4')`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method will remove the element which has class `class4` from the set of matched elements.

---

If you want to filter out `.class1` which doesn't contains `.class4` then use combination of [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) pseudo-class selectors.

```js
$('.class1:not(:has(.class4))').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      some text
    </div>
    <div class='class4'>
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to get content of the element excluding the `.class4` then clone the element using [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method, remove `.class4` and get the content.

```js
console.log(
  $('.class1')
  // clone the element
  .clone()
  // get `.class4` elements
  .find('.class4')
  // remove them
  .remove()
  // back to previous selector
  .end()
  // get html content
  .html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      some text
    </div>
    <div class='class4'>
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```